# Type `Character` missing Using directive or assembly reference-SharpFont/Freetype

Tags: c#, opentk, freetype

I am trying to add text on OpenTK using Sharpfont/ Freetype. I installed SharpFont v4.01 package and SharpFont.Dependencies package. I also added `using SharpFont` in my project but I am still having issue with

```
   Character ch = new Character();
```

I am not sure which library or package missing. What should I add?

*following this answer for adding text [C# OpenTK - Draw string on window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800470/c-sharp-opentk-draw-string-on-window)

Comment: `Character` is a datatype in the project which is related to question [C# OpenTK - Draw string on window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800470/c-sharp-opentk-draw-string-on-window). There is [GitHub](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl)  repository with the project, see [c_sharp_opengl/OpenTK_example_5/FreeTypeFont.cs](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl/blob/master/OpenTK_example_5/FreeTypeFont.cs). Anyway I've added the type `Character` to the linked answer, right now.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Thank you